# Trouble installing dm.xmlsec.binding on Amazon Linux

Tags: python, linux, amazon-web-services, cython

Im attempting to install python-saml onto the latest Amazon Linux for Elasticbeanstalk (64bit Amazon Linux 2016.09 v2.3.3 running Python 2.7)

When it attempts to install dm.xmlsec.binding it fails with

```
Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-build-5dg8_B/dm.xmlsec.binding/setup.py) egg_info for package dm.xmlsec.binding
Running command python setup.py egg_info
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
{standard input}: Assembler messages:
{standard input}:26237: Warning: end of file not at end of a line; newline inserted
{standard input}:26953: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.l'
{standard input}: Error: open CFI at the end of file; missing .cfi_endproc directive
gcc: Internal error: Killed (program cc1)
Please submit a full bug report.
See <http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla> for instructions.
Building lxml version 3.7.3.
Building without Cython.
Using build configuration of libxslt 1.1.28
Building against libxml2/libxslt in the following directory: /usr/lib64
Compile failed: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

No issues on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: You may want to upgrade to the latest Amazon Linux AMI (2017.03) and try it again; usually the `unknown pseudo-op:` error means your toolchain is too old.

Comment: Not currently available for EB

Answer (score 1):

upgrading lxml fixed the issue

```
sudo pip install lxml --upgrade
```